# Conversion from unsigned int to float

Tags: c++, windows, variables, types

```
warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'unsigned int' to 'float', possible loss of data
```

Shouldn't a float be able to handle any value from an int?

```
unsigned int: 0 to 4,294,967,295  
float 3.4E +/- 38 (7 digits)
```

Wiki:

> ```
> The advantage of floating-point representation over fixed-point (and
> ```
>
> integer) representation is that it can
>   support a much wider range of values.

Any insight would be helpful, thanks.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz%28VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 13, accepted):

'unsigned int' and 'float' both use 32 bits to store values. Since a float has a larger range, it necessarily sacrifices some precision. This means that there are some unsigned int values that *cannot* be accurately represented in a float. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza.aspx) provides some more details.

Comment: The MSDN link is to a C# reference, not C++

Answer (score 8):

While `float` supports a wider range of values than `unsigned int`, it does so with less accuracy. Floats have a 23-bit mantissa which, as you posted, is only about 7 decimal digits. unsigned ints support over 9 decimal digits.

Suggestion: use `double`, not `float`.

**Edit:**
Actually, I retract that suggestion; floating-point and integer data types are fundamentally different and are not directly convertible. What integer value do you expect to get for `Single.MaxValue`? For `Single.NegativeInfinity`? Explaining why you want to convert from `float` to `int` would be helpful.

Comment: .. I tihnk he's converting the other way; from int to float.  Still, knowing *why* would certainly help.

Answer (score 3):

As you note in your question, the float only takes 7 digits, as opposed to the 10 digits in INT_MAX. I believe this would be the reason to give a [C4244](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/th7a07tz.aspx) warning at this conversion.

Comment: Yes I did see that, however, based on where the decimal is, shouldn't we be able to represent larger numbers, even thought there are less digits?

Comment: @Tommy: You may want to read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point to learn more about how floating point values are represented, in particular the way the bits are divvied up between mantissa and exponent.

Comment: @Tommy - float can handle the range, but will lose precision (ie., you'll lose some of the least significant digits). That's a loss of data, so the warning is appropriate.

Comment: e.g., try storing both 4_000_000_000 and 4_000_000_001 in your floats, and see what value they have.

Answer (score 3):

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point):

> Single precision, called "float" in the C language family, and "real" or "real*4" in ? Fortran. This is a binary format that occupies 32 bits (4 bytes) and its significand has a precision of 24 bits (about 7 decimal digits).

With an int having 32 bits (generally) and a float having 32 bits (with part reserved for the exponent), there are a lot of int values that can't be exactly represented by the floating point type.

Answer (score 2):

try this to understand the situation

```
float f = 0.0f;
while (f < (INT_MAX-1))
   f++;
```

and you'll see that this is really an infinite loop on systems where int is 32 bits or less.

What will be interesting is to break into the infinite loop and see what the value is for f such that f == f + 1

Comment: The limit is exp(2, 24), because float only has 24 significant bits. `printf("%f\n", float(1<<24)+1)` prints an even number which is obviously wrong.